# ValueError: Endog and Exog are in different size

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have met ValueError: Exog and Ebndog are in different size.

When I type len(y) or len(y_scaled), it returns 0, but it supposed to be five. Hope for help. Thanks in advance.

```
import datetime
import dateutil
import pandas_datareader.data as wb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm

year=5
tickers =["0200.KL"]
ohlc = wb.DataReader(tickers, data_source="yahoo",start=datetime.date.today()-dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(years=year),end=datetime.date.today())

n=5 #get 5 consecutive data

df =ohlc.copy()
series=df["Adj Close"]

slopes=[i*0 for i in range(n-1)]


for i in range(n,len(series)+1):
    y=series[i-n:n]
    x=np.array(range(n))
    #normalize x and y variable
    y_scaled=(y-y.min())/(y.max()-y.min())
    X_scaled=(x-x.min())/(x.max()-x.min())
    
    #add a constant to the equation
    X_scaled=sm.add_constant(X_scaled)
    model=sm.OLS(y_scaled,X_scaled)
    results=model.fit()
    slopes.append(results.params[-1])

#slope coefficient is the theta in radians
slopes_angle=np.rad2degree(np.arctan(np.array(slopes)))
np.array(slopes_angle)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Thank you.

Should be y=df["Adj Close"][i-n:i] instead of y=series[n-i:n]

The full code as below:

```
import datetime
import dateutil
import pandas_datareader.data as wb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm

%matplotlib inline


year=1
tickers ="AAPL"
ohlc = wb.DataReader(tickers, data_source="yahoo",start=datetime.date.today()-dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(years=year),end=datetime.date.today())

n=5 #get 5 consecutive datas

df =ohlc.copy()

slopes=[i*0 for i in range(n-1)]

for i in range(n,len(df)+1):
    y=df["Adj Close"][i-n:i]
    x=np.array(range(n))
    #normalize x and y variable
    y_scaled=(y-y.min())/(y.max()-y.min())
    X_scaled=(x-x.min())/(x.max()-x.min())
    
    #add a constant to the equation
    X_scaled=sm.add_constant(X_scaled)
    model=sm.OLS(y_scaled,X_scaled)
    results=model.fit()
    slopes.append(results.params[-1])

#slope coefficient is the theta in radians
slopes_angle=np.rad2deg(np.arctan(np.array(slopes)))
slopes_angle=np.array(slopes_angle)

plt.plot(slopes_angle)
plt.title("Slope Coefficient of 5 Consecutive Stock Price Data")
plt.ylabel("Slope Coefficient")
plt.xlabel("Period")
plt.show()
```